# Can I avoid registering my app in Azure when using MS Graph?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, graph

I am missing something important here! I just don’t know what to ask for. Maybe I’m getting it all wrong, so feel free to send me in another direction.

To keep things simple – let’s assume that I want to build an app in C# that anyone can download and install on their PC.

The app should be able to read and make changes to the current users Outlook 365 calendar.

So far, I’ve learned through the MS Graph Explorer, that I can use rest calls to manipulate data in my own calendar. Sure – it requires that I login before I can use my own data rather than “demo” data.

I’ve searched for tutorials on how to build Graph applications, to go with the same approach as the MS Graph Explorer. But every tutorial I’ve see so far requires me to register the app in Azure before it will work.

What I don’t understand is – how can the login on the web page with MS Graph Explorer give me access to my calendar without it being registered in my Azure account?

Like – if I create an app as described above – how can it work in any installation if it was not registered in the users Azure portal?

What am I missing?

Basically I’m asking how to replicate the authentication method that is used on the web page with the MS Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Graph Explorer, like the app you would need to register, is a multi-tenant application.

When you register an app, you can choose if it allows sign in from only the current tenant, from *any tenant*, or from *any tenant and personal MS accounts*.

So you do need to register the app, but only in your AAD tenant.
Then when you authenticate the user in the app, you use one of these as the authority:

1. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`: allows authentication from any AAD tenant and with personal MS accounts
2. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations`: allows authentication from any AAD tenant (no personal MS accounts)

The user will then authenticate to their own home tenant and will be required to give consent to scopes required by your app (e.g. permission to read/write calendar data for current user).
After consent, a service principal/enterprise app is created in the user's tenant (if it is an AAD user).
This SP is the local representation of the app.

You can read more about multi-tenancy in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. That will send me on the right path trying to build an application that can utilize the Graph interface.